# 14.10 font issue

Tags: 14.10, fonts

Since I upgraded from 14,04 to 14,10 I am experiencing the following issue.[image]. Pretty much everywhere the font is distorted. Also, when I type the characters sort of delay appearing on the screen, same thing applies for the text selection. Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off hinting in the Tweak tool or Appearances. That fixed it 95% for me.

see  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/554935